# Qual serviço utilizar para receber dados na AWS enviados por MQTT?

Tags: amazon-aws, cloud, mqtt

Qual serviço é recomendado para eu receber dados enviados através de protocolo MQTT? Devo utilizar o **amazon MQ** ? ou o **Aws Iot** ?

O dados serão enviados com frequência de 1 minuto e podem chegar a 200 mensagens por vez, então penso que devo ter um serviço de fila.

Desde já, agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que deve utilizar o Amazon IoT para ouvir e direcionar as mensagens a um serviço SQS afim de que não ocorra perca de mensagens. Então, poderá utilizar um Lambda Function para tratar e direcionar os dados conforme necessitar.

Comment: Obrigado, sua orientação me foi útil.